# How to get cost of uploading data to arweave.net?

Tags: metaplex, metaplex-js, bundlr

```
const { uri, metadata } = await metaplex
  .nfts()
  .uploadMetadata({
    name: "Fake 101",
    image:"https://arweave.net/fCIWuf0GUf6g-f_mN6tKI1txgIgbmb1T6ywYTOfw9Qk",
    description: "This was a dummy description",
    attributes: [
      {
        trait_type: "power",
        value: "100",
      },
      {
        trait_type: "skin",
        value: "Blue",
      },
      {
        trait_type: "sword",
        value: "Iron",
      },
    ],
  })
  .run();
```

How to get how many lamports are required for uploading this data?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this tool called Arweave Fees which will give you the fees in AR Tokens [link](https://ar-fees.arweave.dev/)